# Crsytal Reports on Microsoft Azure Web App Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, crystal-reports

I have my asp.net mvc website live on Azure which i have built in Vs 2015 and MVC5. Everything works fine on localhost. But i dont know what should i do to run my crystal reports on Azure web app? I have found

http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html

on the internet but it does not work for Web Apps on Azure. Any step by step guide to run crystal reports on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you still can't install any third party libraries in Web Apps.  Your options are therefore hosting your crystal reports elsewhere and doing an Iframe style approach in your Web App, or moving your app to either cloud services or a VM.

Comment: So a simple website having a very basic crystal report will not work on Azure?

Comment: It will, but not using your approach.